# ¿Como hacer que mi codigo reconozca la fuente del texto que escribo en HTML?

Tags: html, edittext

Estoy aprendiendo HTML y estoy intentando hacer que la fuente de H1 sea la que deseo pero no se cambia, tengo que descargar algún tipo de extension en VSCode. No se que hacer. estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta.

---

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora, y la primera respuesta esta correcta, eso es exactamente lo que quería hacer, cambiar la letra que va a aparecer en la página web, y justo ayer estaba haciendo la clase de *style* de W3School y me surgió la duda, y muchas gracias por tu ayuda porque tampoco había usado Overflow hasta ayer y me lo recomendaron bastante para las dudas!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">

    <div>
        <h1 style="font-family:Arial;">Hello world</h1>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lee por favor como agregar un [mcve]

Comment: Saliendo de la pregunta: Te recomiendo que hagas algunos de los muchos cursos online gratuito de html, en especifico(w3school, codeblocks,sololearn...), regresando a la pregunta, no entiendo, ¿Quieres cambiar la fuente del editor(VSCode) o quieres cambiar la fuente de la pagina web?, y que es lo que deseas que sea el h1(No lo sabemos porque los desarrolladores todavía no somos adivino(todavía;). ). Tampoco caería mal que nos enseñaras tu intento,

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, ya agregué mi poco progreso hasta ahora! pero seguiré aprendiendo!

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes hacerlo con **css**:
Hay 2 formas:

Una es insertando el css en la etiqueta **h1**

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">Texto de prueba</h1>
```

La otra es por medio de una clase:

```
<head>
   <style>
       .tipo-letra{
          font-family: 'Times New Roman';
       }
   </style>
</head>

...
<h1 class="tipo-letra">Texto de prueba</h1>
```

Comment: Intenta no responder a este tipo de pregunta, hace falta mas detalles para saber lo que quiere, pues yo pienso que el quiere cambiar la fuente de su editor.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar la fuente de texto de tu HTML vas a necesitar usar CSS.
Para ello no se necesita ninguna extensión.

Puedes añadir CSS en el mismo documento donde tienes tu HTML o puedes crear un archivo aparte.

Para añadir CSS en tu mismo documento puedes utilizar la etiqueta *style* que debe de ir dentro de la etiqueta *head* de tu HTML.

La propiedad CSS para cambiar la fuente de texto es: *[font-family](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.php)*

### Ejemplo completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Título del sitio web</title>
  
    <style type="text/css">
        h1
        {
            font-family: "Arial";
        }
    </style>
  
</head>
<body>
<h1>Texto H1 de prueba</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Respecto a la fuente de texto que vas a utilizar: Puedes elegir una de las [fuentes por defecto](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.php) o puedes importar otras desde, por ejemplo: [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

Comment: Intenta no responder a este tipo de pregunta, hace falta mas detalles para saber lo que quiere, pues yo pienso que el quiere cambiar la fuente de su editor.